# Uncaught ReferenceError: elemData is not defined

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

This honestly was not an issue before today. And I havent done anything to my code, so I dont know what happened between today and yesterday that is creating this error. But recently on my wordpress website, When trying to proceed to my checkout page, before the page can load completely, i get this error

```
acf-woocommerce-checkout-script.js?ver=4.8.3:23 Uncaught ReferenceError: elemData is not defined
    at String.<anonymous> (acf-woocommerce-checkout-script.js?ver=4.8.3:23)
    at Function.each (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (acf-woocommerce-checkout-script.js?ver=4.8.3:10)
    at Function.each (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at a.fn.init.each (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at a.fn.init.$.fn.prependOn (acf-woocommerce-checkout-script.js?ver=4.8.3:3)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (acf-woocommerce-checkout-script.js?ver=4.8.3:65)
    at i (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
```

It seems to be caused by my acf plugin. Investigating the plugin shows this section which is the root of the problem:

```
var eventHandle, special, handlers;
                    console.log("looking for elemData", elemData);
                    // copied from jquery core
                    if (!( eventHandle = elemData.handle )) {
                        eventHandle = elemData.handle = function (e) {
                            // Discard the second event of a jQuery.event.trigger() and
                            // when an event is called after a page has unloaded
                            return typeof jQuery !== "undefined" && jQuery.event.triggered !== e.type ? jQuery.event.dispatch.apply(elem, arguments) : undefined;
                        };
                    }
```

Which is strange, because this code has always been part of my theme and never raised an error. Looking at it closer though, this file never makes a variable declaration for `elemData` so I dont know why its referencing it, or what it even does.

What I do know is that when i try to declare it myself:

```
var  elemData= elemData||{};
```

it fixes the referenceError but it produces new errors when trying to submit a form via ajax.

Anyone know what `elemData` is? furthermore, would you know how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems it is looping in a group of elements which not exist. Have you recently edited or ommited any fields of acf froms?

Comment: Probably code that's never been called before and more likely due to something in woocommerce than jQuery. Could be date/time related, which is counter-intuitive but I have known weird unexpected stuff to happen when server or client motherboard clock is wrong or battery dies.

Comment: @AliSheikhpour I was using a field to input time at one point. But have since taken that off. What's strange is that I took that off weeks ago, but this error started today!

Comment: @Roamer-1888 hmmm... do you know any common woocommerce functions that would cause this?

Comment: Also, I still dont see how this code could ever run, given the fact that elemData is not defined in the file, nor is it a global variable of my site.

Comment: "do you know any common woocommerce functions that would cause this?" - sorry no, I know only what I see in your stack trace. That's your best clue.